# Dplyr downsample in pipeline

Tags: r, statistics, dplyr, downsampling

I have a tibble like so:

```
tibble(a = c(1,2,3,4,5), b = c(1,1,1,2,2))
```

I want to randomly downsample the data by the "b" column, like so:

```
tibble(a = c(1,3,4,5), b = c(1,1,2,2))
```

How can I do this entirely in a Dplyr pipeline without changing the data type of the tibble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets the smallest group size (grouped by `b`), and samples that many elements from each group. Not clear if that's what you wanted.

If your tibble is called `df`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(b) %>% 
  add_count %>% 
  slice(sample(row_number(), min(.$n))) %>% 
  select(-n)
```

Comment: This is much better than mine.  I removed it because the OP's conditions are not very clear